# hi i need to write a short shell script that lists all the existing files ignored by your GiT repository. Example:

Tags: git, macos, terminal, gitignore, git-status

%> bash git_ignore.sh | cat -e

.DS_Store$

mywork.c~$

%>

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+list+all+ignored+files

Comment: be more specific with your description and title

Comment: You can call git commands from a bash script (if you need to wrap it in a bash script).

Answer (score 0):

Should be possible via `git ls-files --ignored -X /path/to/gitignore`. No need to write a dedicated script.

Comment: i have a tsk to write script